# Navigator.getInstalledRelatedApps fails in Chrome on Android 12 and 13

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

navigator.getInstalledRelatedApps does not work with my Android 12 system in Chrome.  It is a Samsung tablet, patch level September 1, 2022, if that helps.

We have several Android devices.  Chrome version 113.0.5672 on all them.  So I assume Chrome is not the source of the problem.

Specifically, getInstalledRelatedApps returns an empty array every time on the Android 12 tablet, whether the PWA is installed or not.  On Android 10 and Android 11, it gives a non-empty array with the proper information, if the PWA is installed.

Thankfully, the folks at web.dev created a great little installable page that one can test it on.  https://gira-same-domain.glitch.me/pwa/  The symptoms when I use their wee App are the same as on mine -- desired results with everything besides the Samsung tablet.

I am happy to provide our manifest, but it seems better to direct attention to their simple online playground.

```
{
  "name"                  : "Westrn Wonders",
  "icons"                 : [
    {
      "src"               : "/logo192.png",
      "type"              : "image/png",
      "sizes"             : "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src"               : "/logo512.png",
      "type"              : "image/png",
      "sizes"             : "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url"             : "/",
  "scope"                 : "/",
  "related_applications"  : [{
    "platform"            : "webapp",
    "url"                 : "https://example.hostname.com/manifest.json"
  }],
  "display"               : "standalone",
  "orientation"           : "landscape"
}
```